# REST API Design: Path variable vs request body on UPDATE (Best practices)

Tags: rest, api-design

When creating an UPDATE endpoint to change a resource, the ID should be set in the path variable and also in the request body.
Before updating a resource, I check if the resource exists, and if not, I would respond with 404 Not Found.

Now I ask myself which of the two information I should use and if I should check if both values are the same.

For example:

`PUT /users/42`

```
// request body
{
 "id": 42,
 "username": "user42"
}
```

Comment: "which of the two information I should use" - that depends on what you want to achieve. Would there be any case where updating the ID makes sense?

Comment: No, the ID should'nt be able to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

You should PUT only the properties you can change into the request body and omit read-only properties. So you should check the id in the URI, because it is the only one that should exist in the message.

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to accept the "id" field in the payload. But you have to be sure it is the same as the path parameter. I solve this problem by setting the id field to the value of the path parameter (be sure to explain that in the Swagger of the API). In pseudo-code :

```
idParam = request.getPathParam("id");
object = request.getPayload();
object.id = idParam;
```

So all these calls are equivalent :

```
PUT /users/42 + {"id":"42", ...}
PUT /users/42 + {"id":"41", ...}
PUT /users/42 + {"id":null, ...}
PUT /users/42 + {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the id both in URL and in the body? because now you have to validate that they are both the same or ignore one in any case. If it is a requirement for some reason, than pick which one is the one that is definitive and ignore the other one. If you don't have to have this strange duplication, than I'd say pass it in the body only

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at how HTTP works you might notice that the URI used to send a request to is also used as key for caching results. Any non-safe operation performed on that URI, such as POST, PUT, PATCH, will lead to (intermediary) caches automatically invalidating any stored responses for that URI. As such, if you use an other URI than the actual resource URI you are actually bypassing that feature and risk getting served outdated state from caches. As caching is one of the few constraints REST has simply skipping all caching via certain directives isn't ideal in first place.

In regards to including the ID of the resource or domain entity in the URI and/or in the payload: A common mistake in designing so-called REST APIs is that the domain object is mapped in a 1:1 manner onto a resource. We had a customer once who went through a merger and in a result they ended up with the same products being addressed by multiple IDs. In order to reduce the data in their DB they at one point tried to consolidate their data and continue. But they had to support still the old URIs they exposed for their products. In the end they realized that exposing the product ID via the URI wasn't ideal in their situation as it lead to plenty of downstream changes that affected their customers. As such, a recommendation here is to use UUIDs that don't give the target resource any semantic meaning and don't ever change. If the product ID in the back changes it doesn't affect the exposed URI at all. Sure, you might need a further table/collection to map from the product to the actual resource URI but you in the end designed your system with the eventuality of change which it now is more likely to coop with.

I've read so many times that the product ID shouldn't be part of the resource as it is already present in the URI. First, the whole URI is a unique identifier of that resource and not only a part of it. Next as mentioned above, IMO the product ID shouldn't be part of the URI in first place but it should be part of the resources' state. After all, the product ID is part of the products properties and therefore should be included there accordingly. As such, the media type exposed should contain all the necessities that a client is able to identify the product ID off the payload. The media type the resource's state is exchange with should also provide means to include the ID if you want to perform an update. I.e. if you take HTML as example, here you get served a [HTML form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) by the server which basically teaches you where to send the request to, which HTTP operation to use, which media-type to marshal the request with and the actual properties of the resource, including the ones you are not meant to change. HTML does this i.e. via hidden input fields. Other form-based media types, such as [HAL forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html), [JsonForms](https://jsonforms.io/) or [Ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms), might provide other mechanisms though.

So, to sum my post up:

- Don't map the product ID onto URIs. Use a mapping from product ID to UUIDs instead
- Use form-based media-types that support clients in creating requests. These media types should allow to include unmodifiable properties, such as hidden input fields and the like